# Prestashop 1.7 problem to access backoffice

Tags: prestashop

when I m trying to access my back office I get this message

For security reasons, you cannot connect to the back office until you have:

deleted the /install folder
Please then access this page by the new URL (e.g. http://localhost/prestashop/backoffice/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to physically remove/delete `/install' folder from your installation.

Comment: yes that was the problem but I m facing another problem the back office is so slow